# Ubuntu booting slow

Tags: boot, dual-boot

[image]

I tried many Linux distros Ubuntu is my favorite but I don't understand why Ubuntu booting time is longer in my "Dell Inspiron 14,3467 model".

It takes around 1 minute to boot. In other OS like Windows it takes maximum 15 seconds.

- I tried to extend RAM but still Ubuntu takes long time to boot.
- I clean install Ubuntu only but still Ubuntu takes much time.
- I tried many methods which are posted in the forum but none of them can fix the issue.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo systemd-analyze` and `sudo systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: ...and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Your computer RAM space may need to be freed up. Your processor(s) may be wearing out. How old is your laptop?

Comment: Your filesystem is taking 15 seconds to become ready. That's a few seconds longer than usual. Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: Snapd is taking 5 seconds to come up (this time), That usually means that it is updating, and will be much shorter next time. If it's 15-20s every time, then you have a problem.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`, and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application SMART Data & Tests data.

Comment: @Jeff re: "*Your processor(s) may be wearing out.*" Really?!? How does that happen? Your entire comment is just silly.